# Writing binary data to middle of a sparse file

Tags: python, file-io, binary, p2p, sparse-matrix

I need to compile a binary file in pieces with pieces arriving in random order (yes, its a P2P project)

```
def write(filename, offset, data) 
    file.open(filename, "ab")
    file.seek(offset) 
    file.write(data) 
    file.close()
```

Say I have a 32KB write(f, o, d) at offset 1MB into file and then another 32KB write(f, o, d) at offset 0

I end up with a file 65KB in length (i.e. the gap consisting of 0s between 32KB - 1MB is truncated/disappears)

I am aware this may appear an incredibly stupid question, but I cannot seem to figure it out from the file.open(..) modes

Advice gratefully received.

*** UPDATE

My method to write P2P pieces ended up as follows (for those who may glean some value from it)

```
def writePiece(self, filename, pieceindex, bytes, ipsrc, ipdst, ts): 
    file = open(filename,"r+b")
    if not self.piecemap[ipdst].has_key(pieceindex):
        little = struct.pack('<'+'B'*len(bytes), *bytes) 
        # Seek to offset based on piece index 
        file.seek(pieceindex * self.piecesize)
        file.write(little)
        file.flush()
        self.procLog.info("Wrote (%d) bytes of piece (%d) to %s" % (len(bytes), pieceindex, filename))

    # Remember we have this piece now in case duplicates arrive 
    self.piecemap[ipdst][pieceindex] = True
    file.close()
```

Note: I also addressed some endian issues using struct.pack which plagued me for a while.

For anyone wondering, the project I am working on is to analyse BT messages captured directly off the wire.

Comment: You did not `seek` to the end and write there before closing?

Comment: That code doesn't run. What is the actual code you use?

Comment: I need sleep - this is such a rooky question I cannot believe I asked it. Apologies. 

I needed to use: file.open("r+b") to achieve my intended goal.

Comment: Now I have a file with 32KB at offset 0 and 32KB at offset 1MB with rest of the file consisting of zeroes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> filename = 'tempfile'
>>> def write(filename,data,offset):
...     try:
...         f = open(filename,'r+b')
...     except IOError:
...         f = open(filename,'wb')
...     f.seek(offset)
...     f.write(data)
...     f.close()
...
>>> write(filename,'1' * (1024*32),1024*1024)
>>> write(filename,'1' * (1024*32),0)
>>> os.path.getsize(filename)
1081344
```

Answer (score 4):

You opened the file in append (`"a"`) mode. All writes are going to the end of the file, irrespective of the calls to `seek()`.

Comment: Sorry for my haste in entering the code example. To create a file with pieces of data at various offsets and otherwise filled with zeroes I used file.open("r+b") mode and just seek-ed and wrote data to the file as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'r+b' rather than 'ab'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like there's not a lot of point in trying to assemble the file until all the pieces of it are there. Why not keep the pieces separate until all are present, then write them to the final file in order? That's what most P2P apps do, AFAIK.

Comment: You think that's what bittorrent does with a 2GB download? What are you doing to do, keep the pieces in memory?

Comment: Save each piece, as it's received, to a separate file, then merge when done. I seem to recall that's what e.g. Limewire does, but I don't know about most torrent clients.